# Reactions involved in Titanium Anodisation

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

I am writing up a lab report investigating titanium anodisation and producing oxide layers. After some searching, all I can find is the reaction $\ce{Ti + O2 \to TiO2}$, which I am having no trouble understanding.

However, I seem to be confused/mislead by the simplicity of this. The whole unit is about electrochemistry and redox reactions but I cannot find any examples (or seem to produce any either - I have tried generalizing from the rusting of iron in water) of half reactions or anything similar.

I have come about as far as including the redox reactions for the hydrolysis of water and then jumping to the above reaction but am unsure where to go from here.

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to locate what appears to be a useful summary of reactions and reduction potentials that are all titanium-specific [here](http://objetoseducacionais2.mec.gov.br/bitstream/handle/mec/10496/22.htm).

The reaction $\ce{ Ti + O2 -> TiO2}$ is illustrative of $\ce{Ti}$ being oxidized while oxygen is reduced. I agree with you that it is simplistic-looking and might not appear as traditional an example of redox chemistry as you require.

You might investigate the high-temperature reaction of titanium metal and water (steam), which produces $\ce {TiO2}$ and $\ce{H2}$ gas (titanium is oxidized, hydrogen is reduced), which might be a little clearer. This reaction (and several others) are given on the page I've linked above.